# focus() event after js confirm() / Firefox vs Chrome behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I have a complex web application that relies in part on the `focus()` event and I'm running into some difficulty when using a `confirm()` box inside a function.

**It seems that exiting a confirm box triggers a `focus()` event on close, but the behavior is different in Firefox than in Chrome.  Why?  At the very least, I need to find a way to make these events consistent across browsers.**

I've put together and example below that illustrates what I mean.

If you confirm the box in Firefox (v55.0.2) you'll get a `focus()` event triggered on the initial `<input>` box, and then the function will subsequently trigger a second `focus()` event on the target element (the next `<input>` element).

By contrast, if you do the same thing in Chrome (v60.0.3112.101), you'll get *two* `focus()` events triggered on the *next* `<input>` element - one from the function and one from presumably from the confirm dialog.

*Edit: Tested this on Chrome v49.0.2623.112 and there is only **one** `focus()` event (the one explicitly triggered by my function) which is what I'd expect and things behaved when I first developed the app.  Really confused now as there are three distinct ways that various browsers handle exiting a `confirm()` dialog.*

```js
$('form').on('keypress', 'input', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    validate(this);
  }
});
$('form').on('focus', 'input[type=text]', function() {
  var n = +$(this).next('span').text();
  n++;
  $(this).next('span').text(n);
});

function validate(self) {
  var next = $(self).closest('div').nextAll('div').first();
  if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
    next.find('input[type=text]').prop('disabled', false).focus();
  }

}
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Type some text and hit return:</h2>
<form>
  <div><input autocomplete="off" type="text"> Focus Events: <span class="info">0</span></div>
  <div><input autocomplete="off" disabled type="text"> Focus Events: <span class="info">0</span></div>
  <div><input autocomplete="off" disabled type="text"> Focus Events: <span class="info">0</span></div>
  <div><input autocomplete="off" disabled type="text"> Focus Events: <span class="info">0</span></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a flag to indicate that the confirm box is displayed, and ignore all focus events while the flag is on. Once the confirm box is closed, you reset the flag asynchronously, just before focusing the next field (as suggested in [Terry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45900271/1009922)).

```js
var isConfirming = false;

$('form').on('keypress', 'input', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    validate(this);
  }
});
$('form').on('focus', 'input[type=text]', function() {
  // Ignore the focus events caused by the confirm box
  if (!isConfirming) {
    var n = +$(this).next('span').text();
    n++;
    $(this).next('span').text(n);
  }
});

function validate(self) {
  var next = $(self).closest('div').nextAll('div').first(),
    nextInput = next.find('input[type=text]');

  isConfirming = true; // Set the flag before showing the confirm box

  if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
    nextInput.prop('disabled', false);

    // Reset the flag and change focus asynchronously 
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      isConfirming = false;
      nextInput.focus();
    }, 0);
  } else {
    // Reset the flag asynchronously 
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      isConfirming = false;
    }, 0);
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Type some text and hit return:</h2>
<form>
  <div><input autocomplete="off" type="text"> Focus Events: <span class="info">0</span></div>
  <div><input autocomplete="off" disabled type="text"> Focus Events: <span class="info">0</span></div>
  <div><input autocomplete="off" disabled type="text"> Focus Events: <span class="info">0</span></div>
  <div><input autocomplete="off" disabled type="text"> Focus Events: <span class="info">0</span></div>
</form>
```

Comment: well that's ridiculously simple and a bit hacky but it it does indeed produce consistent results across all browsers I tested.

Answer (score 2):

To summarise your question, the issue you face is:

- Firefox triggering focus event on the current and the next input element upon confirmation
- Chrome triggering focus event **twice** on the next input element (in fact, I can also reproduce this in OS X Safari, likely because Blink and Webkit once belong to the same branch)

Although I cannot confirm the inner workings on the browsers, it appears that their JS engines have different ways of resolving a race condition. Basically, the input element will be "re-focused" when a user exists an app-level modal (alert, confirm, etc.), but different browser engine decides when the focus event is triggered.

If you want to force both browsers to trigger the focus event on the next element and dedupe it, you can simply perform the focusing at the end of the callstack, i.e.:

```
var next = $(self).closest('div').nextAll('div').first(),
    nextInput = next.find('input[type=text]');

if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
    // Remove disabled prop
    nextInput.prop('disabled', false);

    // Focus at end of callstack
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        nextInput.focus();
    }, 0);
}
```

See proof-of-concept example below:

```js
$('form').on('keypress', 'input', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    validate(this);
  }
});
$('form').on('focus', 'input[type=text]', function() {
  var n = +$(this).next('span').text();
  n++;
  $(this).next('span').text(n);
});

function validate(self) {
  var next = $(self).closest('div').nextAll('div').first(),
      nextInput = next.find('input[type=text]');
      
  if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
    // Remove disabled prop
    nextInput.prop('disabled', false);
    
    // Focus at end of callstack
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      nextInput.focus();
    }, 0);
  }

}
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Type some text and hit return:</h2>
<form>
  <div><input autocomplete="off" type="text"> Focus Events: <span class="info">0</span></div>
  <div><input autocomplete="off" disabled type="text"> Focus Events: <span class="info">0</span></div>
  <div><input autocomplete="off" disabled type="text"> Focus Events: <span class="info">0</span></div>
  <div><input autocomplete="off" disabled type="text"> Focus Events: <span class="info">0</span></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Terry, unfortunately this still doesn't resolve my issue. Tried it on 4 different browsers with varying results. The primary issue being that in *some* there is a `focus()` event triggered immediately on the initial `<input>` element, while in others there is not. In my application that `focus()` event has consequences to the way things behave.  As things stand it's not going to work properly until I can change the code to get a consistent result from all browsers.

Comment: To clarify, it's the first focus - the one that's triggered by exiting the confirm dialog that's causing me issues - especially since it seems to always happens before any other event (when it does happen)

Comment: What I really need is a way to either (a) prevent that event or (b) recognize it in my code and ignore it accordingly